# Prevent the parent object from being changed by an array of child objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, parent-child, p5.js

I have a object that has many child objects and I only want the children to change a specific value, not affecting the parent object. In short, the children have values that WILL change but the children are changing the parent as well, which is bad.

Only Relevant JS:

```
let p1 = {super:{vel:{x:3,y:0}, timeLeft:100}} // Very Shortened player objects
let p2 = {y:100}

var supers = {p1:[], p2:[]};
function draw(){    
    superProject();

    if (p1.super.timeLeft >= 1 && p1.super.type == 'MISSILE'){
        p1.super.timeLeft--;
        let randY = Math.round(random(50, 150)); 
        let missile = {x:40, y:randY, vel:p1.super.vel, dist:{x:0, y:0}}
        supers.p1.push(missile);
    }
}

function superProject(){
    if (supers.p1.length > 0){
        for (let i = 0; i < supers.p1.length; i++){
            supers.p1[i].x += supers.p1[i].vel.x;
            supers.p1[i].y += supers.p1[i].vel.y;

            let distY = 0;
            distY = p2.y - supers.p1[i].y;

            let distX = 0;
            distX = 170 - supers.p1[i].x

            supers.p1[i].dist.x = distX;
            supers.p1[i].dist.y = distY;

            if (distY > 0){
                supers.p1[i].vel.y += 1;
            } else if (distY < 0){
                supers.p1[i].vel.y -= 1;
            }

            circle(supers.p1[i].x, supers.p1[i].y, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

[Link](https://codepen.io/deathcaller120-0/pen/BayYLXx?editors=1000) to full source. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Did not understand what you need... what you mean with *parent variable and child variable*? Are you talking about objects? And also, I think that HTML is not relevant here, if not, remove, see [mcve]. Show us where is the code you are attempting to do what you need

Comment: > 690 lines of code is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please reduce the code to the essential parts.

Comment: If this is your code, can't you just not update the parents?

Comment: I'm not updating the parents manually, its doing it on its own. And that is what I need help with as I don't know why its happening